# Duplicating data in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I am making a database validation system. Upon validation, the handler is supposed to send the data to an email address, while simultaneously updating the data to another database. The values of id, name, board, query and rand are received from the previous page. 
Now, with the given code, I am unable to update the table named 'answers' within my database. The line of code for this functionality is in bold.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = '';
$dbname = "bsp";

$conn1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$id="";
$value = "";
$name = "";
$board = ""; 
$query="";
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$board = $_POST['board'];
$query = $_POST['query'];
$rand = $_POST['rand'];
$value=$_POST['option'];
$to="";
$subject="";
$msg="";
$headers="";
if($value=='delete')
    {
        $sql="DELETE FROM rti WHERE ID=$id";
            if ($conn1->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn1->error;
            }
    }
else if($value=='validate')
    {
        **$sql="INSERT INTO answers (name, board, query, rand) VALUES (\"$name\", \"$board\", \"$query\", \"$rand\")";**
        if($board=='BRCA')
            {
                $to = 'email@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'RTI Query: Do not reply to this email.';
                $msg = "Your code is " . $rand . ".";
                $msg .= " Visit localhost/BSP/landing.php and post the code, and subsequently your answer.";
                $headers = 'From: contact@yoursite.com';
                mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);    
            }
        else if($board=='BSW')
            {
                $to = 'email@rediffmail.com';
                $subject = 'RTI Query: Do not reply to this email.';
                $msg = $query;
                $headers = 'From: contact@yoursite.com';
                mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
            }   
        else if($board=='BSA')
            {
                $to = 'email@iitd.ac.in';
                $subject = 'RTI Query: Do not reply to this email.';
                $msg = $query;
                $headers = 'From: contact@yoursite.com';
                mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
            }
        else if($board=='BSP')
            {
                $to = 'email@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'RTI Query: Do not reply to this email.';
                $msg = $query;
                $headers = 'From: contact@yoursite.com';
                mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
            }
        else if($board=='BHM')
            {
                $to = 'email@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'RTI Query: Do not reply to this email.';
                $msg = $query;
                $headers = 'From: contact@yoursite.com';
                mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
            }

     }

if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)==TRUE)
    {
        echo "The mail was sent successfully.";
    }



$conn1->close();
?>
```

Comment: You arent executing a query in the code block where you are attempting to insert into `answers` All you are doing is assigning the string to `$sql`

Comment: Oh damn. Thanks for pointing that out. Works perfectly now.

Comment: No problem. Easy oversight